# Redis on Appharbor - Booksleeve GetString exception

Tags: redis, appharbor, booksleeve

i am trying to setup Redis on appharbor. I have followed their instructions and again i have an issue with the Booksleeve API. Here is the code i am using to make it work initially:

```
               var connectionUri = new Uri(url);

                using (var redis = new RedisConnection(connectionUri.Host, connectionUri.Port, password: connectionUri.UserInfo.Split(new[] { ':' }, 2)[1]))
                {
                    redis.Strings.Set(1, "greeting", "welcome to remember your stuff!");

                    try
                    {
                        var task = redis.Strings.GetString(1, "greeting");

                        redis.Wait(task);

                        ViewBag.Message = task.Result;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        // It throws an exception trying to wait for the task?
                    }
                }
```

However, the issue is that it sets the string correctly, but when trying to retrieve the same string from the key value store, it throws a timeout exception waiting for the task to eexecute. However, this code works on my local redis server connection.

Am i using the API in a wrong way? or is this something related to Appharbor?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like a `SqlConnection`, you need to call `Open()` (otherwise your messages are queued for delivery).

***Unlike*** `SqlConnection`, you should **not** fire up a `RedisConnection` each time you need it - it is intended to be used as a shared, thread-safe, multiplexer - i.e. a single connection is held somewhere and used by lots and lots of unrelated callers. Unless of course you only need to do one thing!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and hints!..The connection now works. It goes over the wait line. but for some reason on the task.Result line i get the following: // Error processing data: A critical operation failed: 1: SELECT.. is this an appharbor redis issue?.. i could get the data on my local server?

Comment: @DoubleScorpio do you have 2 databases? Databases are 0-based; if you only have 1, use DB 0.

Comment: i set to DB 0 and It Works!!!.. thanks for your help!.. i was just playing around with the client, but now that it works i will restructure my code and build something good with it :).. Thanks again!

Comment: @DoubleScorpio - the number of DBs is a server configuration option, btw